# Error Handling using the Reactive Framework

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, onerror

I have designed what is essentially a propertychanged listener - i.e. when Instance.A changes, call OnAChanged()

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(Instance,"PropertyChanged")
          .Where(e => e.EventArgs.PropertyName == "A")
          .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
          .Subscribe(search =>
              OnAChanged((PropertyChangedEventArgsEx)search.EventArgs), s =>
                  OnError(s));
```

This works totally fine (without the `s => OnError(s)` part).

However, I wanted to test exception handling. I modified by `OnAChanged()` method to just throw a new exception. However, the exception is thrown, and `OnError` never gets called, and my application crashes. Am I misunderstanding the usage of `OnError`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding OnError - OnError is a property of the IObservable. Event-based IObservables never OnError (because there's no such thing as an "Event Exception" or something). If you had a different source, like Observable.Start, you could see the OnError.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Am I correct in just having a bunch of FromEventPatterns, each of which listen for a different property change? Or is there a better practice that I can adhere to? I'm basically just looking to implement the observer pattern.

Comment: You can do that, sure - ReactiveUI makes this far easier though, it's an MVVM framework explicitly designed to work alongside Rx